# How can I eliminate the left recursive in CFG?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, context-free-grammar

I came across a problem when studying CFG. I need your help.

There are productions. A, B, C are non-terminals and '(',')','+','*',num are terminals.

> A->A+B|B
>
> B->B*C|C
>
> C->(A)|num

The problem is, there exist left recursion serially.(first production and second one)
How could I rearrange these productions to eliminate the left-recursion?

Comment: If that one doesn't work for you, there are dozens more. Search for *eliminate left recursion*.

Comment: @rici thank you! I found the answer also in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion.